# Href # Link on page Requires back button to be hit twice on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some tabs on a page and there is a href to get to specific parts of the page.

```
<a class="page_link" href="#tabA">Section1</a>
```

All the content is on the same page and the link is just to part of the page. This then updates the url with #tabA

If i hit the back button on the browser i have to hit it twice to get back to the previous page. Is there any way to prevent having to hit back twice?

There is also some JS in order to track the history

```
const hash = window.location.hash ? window.location.hash.substr(1) : false;
const panel = hash ? document.getElementById(hash) : false;
const link = hash ? self.querySelector(`[href='#${hash}']`) : false;

window.history.pushState(null, null, panelId);
```

I have the following to close and open the tab, but nothing to pop history or replace it, is something missing

```
const openPanel = (self, link, target) => {
  closeActiveTab(self);

  link.classList.add('activeTab');

  link.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
  target.classList.add('activeTab');
  target.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');

};

const closeActiveTab = (el) => {
  const tabs = el.getElementsByClassName('activeTab');
  while (tabs.length) {

    const selTab = tabs[0];

    selTab.classList.remove('activeTab');
    selTab.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
  }

};
```

Comment: You have not posted enough information for us to know. Perhaps you are using some kind on framework that changes the tabs?

Comment: Can you please share the rest of your code. With the given information I don't see an issue on my side

Comment: Hello sorry i have updated it

Comment: if you right click the back arrow in chrome you can see if you have been redirected twice to same location, thats maybe why, it's worth checking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to try doesn't change the url at all. You can scroll to anchor section or show tab without changing page hash. If it isn't required, ofcourse.

If it is required to have a hash in the url, you can use `history.replaceState()` instead of `history.pushState()`. This method will replace current state and to go back you can press the back button once as you wanted.

Comment: This works if i just browse to one tab on the page and click back. If i click on two tabs and then back it doesn't go back to the first tab it goes back to the page i came from? But progress :)

Comment: If you need go back to previous tab – why don't just simply make some variable to store visited tabs? And if there is previous tab you can make pushState and if there isn't visited tab – replaceState.